# How can I clean rubbers side (gasket) of refrigerator?

Tags: cleaning, home

The side rubber (gasket) of my refrigerator is turning black. How can I clean it? I used vinegar and lemon, but it's not effective.

Comment: Welcome to lifehacks! More information about the material of the gasket or even a picture would be very useful to help answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **rubbing alcohol**? Cheap & effective solvent in my experience. Perhaps apply & scrub with an old toothbrush? 
If still stained with grime, possibly try OTCounter cleaning products:
 1) is those ‘magic eraser’ products that work like a chemical sponge when dampened.
 2)try SOS pads, those abrasive/soapy blue scrubbing products?

Perhaps reframe/rationalize: acceptance. In the end little or no harm, how much effort does this dirty gasket warrant? 
Best of luck!

AX

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely mold, and you'll get the best results from some proprietary mold remover spray or liquid that simultaneously kills the mold to inhibit further growth, and bleaches it so the remnants/any staining of the substrate becomes less visible

Answer (score 0):

Mix baking soda, water and vinegar in a plastic container and apply directly to the mold. The mixture is best sprayed on from an empty window spray type bottle. The mixture will fizz and become inactive so has to be used immediately after mixing.

Jatt

Answer (score 0):

You can use various Eco-cleaning ideas suggested by [Neatspiration](https://www.neatspiration.com.au) to make your fridge completely clean.